# Cannot use pythonnet on .NET Core (ConsoleApp.dll has exited with code 0)

Tags: c#, python, .net-core, python-3.7, python.net

I'm trying to use [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) on .NET Core on a Linux machine.
I have compiled it using the ReleaseMonoPY3 configuration, on Windows, before copying the output dll over to my Linux machine.
I have also installed Python 3.7 on my Linux machine.

When running the example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

        dynamic sin = np.sin;
        Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

        double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
        Console.WriteLine(c);

        dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
        Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

        dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
        Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

        Console.WriteLine(a * b);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My application terminates. It terminates on this line:

```
using (Py.GIL())
```

I am not getting any error messages whatsoever. It simply exists:

```
The program '[19030] ConsoleApp.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How can I make pythonnet work on Linux .NET Core?
There's obviously some P/Invoking errors. Is it possible to get to them somehow?